# Firebase Notification with Xcode 8 iOS 10 Swift 3

Tags: firebase, push-notification, swift3, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to follow the tutorial to configure my iOS app to receive notifications from Firebase. I'm able to receive the message when the app in foreground, but NOT in background.

Here is the data format I received when the app in foreground mode:

```
[AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = 80;
    e = 1;
}, AnyHashable("from"): 7151xxxxxx8, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): me.caoyang.iOSPushNotification]
```

I have:

1. Enabled the *Push Notifications*, *Background Modes (Remote notifications)* and *Keychain Sharing* under *Capabilities*.
2. Toggled *FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled* and *FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled* under Info.plist with YES or NO option many times.
3. Includes GoogleService-Info.plist into project
4. and yes, I uploaded the .p12 file.

My questions:

1. What should be the value of variable `gcmMessageIDKey`?
2. What can I do or debug or try to make it work?

**ViewController.swift file**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //_ = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
    //FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/news")
}

@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()

    print("token: \(token)")
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift file**

```
//
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Google Inc.
//
//  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//  limitations under the License.
//

import UIKit
import UserNotifications

import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]

        FIRApp.configure()

        // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)
        // [END add_token_refresh_observer]

        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        // Won't connect since there is no token
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
            return;
        }

        // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the InstanceID token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    }

    // [START connect_on_active]
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END connect_on_active]

    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]
```

Comment: Hi. Are you sending messages through the Firebase Console or from your own App Server? Can you post a sample a payload or at least the details of the sample messages you're sending? :)

Comment: @AL. From console

Comment: So nothing appears, not even in the notification tray? That's odd.